# How to commit changes to access database using datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Please help, I got the code below from a book but it doesnt seem to work:

```
 try 
   oledbDataAdapter1.update("GH")
   Catch ex as exception
      msbox(ex.tostring)
   end try
```

I'm using ms access 2003, here is my connection string:

```
       Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data     Source=F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from GH where IDNUMBER= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", cn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am not sure what you are trying to update.  The update method requires a dataset or datatable.  Here is a link to the MSDN website with more information about the update method - [oledbdataadapter.update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.update.aspx).

Here is an example of what I believe you are trying to do.

```
dim oledbDataAdapter1 as new oledbDataAdapter("Select * from GH where IDNUMBER= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ","Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data     Source=F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb")

dim modifieddataset as dataset
oledbDataAdapter1.fill(modifieddataset)

'Make changes to dataset
...

try
     oledbDataAdapter1.update(modifieddataset)  
catch ex as exception
     msbox(ex.tostring)
end try
```

Finally, you should avoid allowing user input to be put directly into you SQL string.  It allows SQL Injection.  Here is an article that will better explain the issue - [SQL Injection](http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/86223).  HTH